# Unable to run shell command with docker?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, docker, double-quotes

I have installed docker on Ubuntu 14.04. Now when i am trying to create one test job in docker, i am getting the below error:

> **$ sample_job=$(docker run -d busybox /bin/sh -c “while true; do echo**
> **Docker; sleep 1; done”)**
>
> -bash: command substitution: line 228: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
>
> -bash: command substitution: line 228: `docker run -d busybox /bin/sh -c “while true; do echo Docker; sleep 1; done”)'

I am following the below blog for starting with docker: http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/docker/docker-tutorial-series-part-2-the-15-commands

Could someone help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks!!

Comment: Replace both `“`  by `"`.

Comment: @Cyrus Nice catch!! thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus):

Replaced `“` by `"`

> $ sample_job=$(docker run -d busybox /bin/sh -c "while true; do echo
>   Docker; sleep 1; done")